# ARMAX for Bitcoin prediction via sentiment

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, endogeneity

I am looking for correlation between social sentiment of BTC and the financial value of BTC. My approach is to use a time-series model to predict the bitcoin value at t+1 based on multiple input variables:

- **a**: bitcoin price at time t, t-1, ..., t-n
- **b**: sentiment (created via sentiment analysis on tweets containing #BTC and averaged over the interval) for tweets in intervals [t, t+1], [t-1, t], ...: Gets value between -1 (negative) and 1 (positive)
- **c**: amount of tweets containing #BTC in the intervals [t, t+1], [t-1, t], ...

Am I correct in the assumption that an ARMAX model with endogenous variable a and exogenous variables b and c would be the right approach? Or do I need to use a VARMA model with a,b,c as endogenous variables?

edit: According to the following Model Results for my VARMA(1,1) model fitted on 1 year of hourly bitcoin price, sentiment and tweet-amount, all my p values seem to indicate statistical significance for all input variables. 
y1 is the amount of tweets, y2 is the sentiment and y3 is the bitcoin price

[image]

Comment: Given the volatile nature of BTC prices & noisy nature of human language data, I'd expect such model to have pretty low predictive power. Are you planning to publish it? I'm curious about the results.

Comment: I want to look into this for my master's thesis. But my background is electrical engineering and management, so I am slightly out of my depth knowledge wise. Independent of the most likely low predictive power, I am looking for hints on whether my suggested approaches are flawed

Answer (score 1):

Your model can potentially be useful. As a first approach, I think you can give it a try. What I would do is working with a time series of bitcoin prizes (or returns), not just "bitcoin prize at time t", Your b and c variables could then work as external regressors.

You can also treat b and c as variables evolving in time and work with multivariate time series model for a more complete study (current feelings on Bitcoin may affect its value today, but why not tomorrow or next week?)

Prizes/returns from other cryptocurrencies are also a good source of information for the model. They could be included as components of the time series.

Finally, avoid the so commonly made mistake of thinking that what people write on Twitter is a good estimate of what society actually thinks on a topic!

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! 

I might have been unclear. All three variables a,b,c are indeed already a time series. I will adjust the initial question accordingly.

I don't really understand the difference in the two approaches you mentioned: What do you mean by having "b and c variables as external regressors"? And how does this differenciate from "treating b and c as variables evolving in time"?

Is this comparable to my initial question about ARMAX vs VARMA?

Comment: @Sentiment_BTC If you did not use them as time series, their value at the given instant could be used as external regressors. If you are for the "everything is a time series" approach, then just ignore it and go for VAR / VARMA / VGARCH / VWhtaever